# When installing the GUI fails to load and only shows wallpaper

Tags: system-installation

As per the title it describes most of what happens. I install the 32-bit ISO on a memory stick with unetbootin and when I boot the boot logo displays fine then it goes to the wallpaper with nothing else. No icons, taskbars. Nothing. I can access the terminal with alt+f2 but the GUI won't restart. I've tried mutliple different distros of linux and even if they install I still get stuck on just the wallpaper with no elements. I'm using a Integrated CPU board: http://ark.intel.com/products/69041/Intel-Desktop-Board-D2550DC2

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Open the Terminal

```
sudo apt install software-properties-common 
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:elementary-os/os-patches
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt remove elemntary-desktop
sudo apt purge elemntary-desktop
Sudo apt update
sudo apt install elemntary-desktop
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo reboot now
```

Tell us if that helps.